# Mouse control is not working with object movement. Fabric Js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am trying to create a responsive canvas and while I am doing that I am facing issues related to the transform tool object movement and selection.

Can you please help me where I am doing wrong?

In this code, I am creating canvas dynamically using JSON and underscore js

Here are the steps

1. Launch the code
2. Resize te window
3. Check now you will see controls are not working.

Here are my code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Fit Canvas Within Perticular area Using this code your canvas will fit inside any container </title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://5945822.swh.strato-hosting.eu//ma-test/test-0124-2/js/all.js"></script>


 <script type="text/html" id='canvas-template'>
        <% _.each(viewList,function(view,key,list){   %>

                    <div class="view-wrapper" data-editor-view-id="<%=view.viewId %>"  style="width:<%=view.imageWidth%>px; height:<%=view.imageHeight%>px; position:relative">
                        <img data-component-type="product-image" src="https://livingannuityspecialist.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/retirement.jpg" class="productImage"  width="<%=view.imageWidth%>" height="<%=view.imageHeight%>"  />
                        <div class="canvas-wrapper"  style="position:absolute; width:<%=view.width%>px; height:<%=view.height%>px; left: <%=view.left%>px; top: <%=view.top%>px;">
                                <canvas id="<%=view.applicationType%>_<%=view.viewId%>" width="<%=view.width%>" height="<%=view.height%>" ></canvas>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        <% }); %>

</script>


<body>

<div  id="target_container"  style="width:100%; height:100%;">



</div>
<button onClick="addImage()">Add Image </button>


<script>

/* List of canvas */ 
var canvas;
    var viewDetailsList=[
        {
        "width":1880,"height":977,"top":0,"left":0,"imageWidth":1880,"imageHeight":977,"viewId":2603,"title":"front","imageSrc":"1.png","applicationType":"editor"
        }]

        var template = $("#canvas-template").html();
        $('#target_container').html(_.template(template)({viewList:viewDetailsList}));

        var $targetContainer=$('#target_container');

        /* Calculate Scale Factor according to Outer container */
        function calculateScaleFactor(viewId) {
            var viewContainer = $('[data-editor-view-id="' + viewId + '"]');
            var cssWidthScale = $targetContainer.width() / viewContainer.width();
            var cssHeightScale = $targetContainer.height() / viewContainer.height();
            var scaleFactor = Math.min(cssWidthScale, cssHeightScale);
            return scaleFactor;
        }
        /* Fit Canvas to perticular target or div according to width and height of div 
         Let's say If I wan to fix perticular canvas of width 1000px and height 1000px to 500px by 500px then I waant to calculate the scaleFactor for fitting 1000px canvas inside the 500px area. 
        */
        function setCanvasCSS(viewId){
            var scaleFactor= calculateScaleFactor(viewId);
            var viewContainer = $('[data-editor-view-id="' + viewId + '"]');
            var scaling= 'scale(' + scaleFactor + ',' + scaleFactor + ')'
            viewContainer.css({'transform': scaling,'-webkit-transform': scaling,'-moz-transform': scaling,'-o-transform': scaling});
            var leftPos = ($targetContainer.width() - viewContainer.width() * scaleFactor) / 2;
            var topPos = ($targetContainer.height() - viewContainer.height() * scaleFactor) / 2;
            viewContainer.css({'left': leftPos,'top':topPos});

        }
        /* Iteration for Multiple Canvas*/
        $.each(viewDetailsList,function(key, view){
            setCanvasCSS(view.viewId);
        })

        /*Window.Resize canvas setting */
        $(window).resize(function(){
            setCanvasCSS(viewDetailsList[0].viewId);
                canvas.getObjects().forEach(function(obj){
                obj.setCoords();
                canvas.renderAll();
                 canvas.calcOffset();
            })

          });

         /* Create Canvas */
         canvas = new fabric.Canvas('editor_2603');

        /* Add Image */
         function addImage(){
            var imgURL = 'http://i.imgur.com/8rmMZI3.jpg';
             var imgObj = new Image();
            imgObj.src = imgURL
            imgObj.onload = function() {
              var image = new fabric.Image(imgObj);
              image.set({
                left: 10,
                top: 10,
              }).scale(0.2);
              canvas.add(image);
              image.setCoords();
              canvas.renderAll();
              canvas.calcOffset();

            };


         }
</script>  



<style>
 #target_container{border:1px solid red;}
 .view-wrapper{transform-origin:0% 0%;overflow:hidden;}
 .canvas-wrapper{border: 5px solid green;}

</style>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the fixed I have updated the latest fabric.js and its working properly for me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Fit Canvas Within Perticular area Using this code your canvas will fit inside any container </title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.0.0/fabric.js"></script>


 <script type="text/html" id='canvas-template'>
        <% _.each(viewList,function(view,key,list){   %>

                    <div class="view-wrapper" data-editor-view-id="<%=view.viewId %>"  style="width:<%=view.imageWidth%>px; height:<%=view.imageHeight%>px; position:relative">
                        <img data-component-type="product-image" src="https://livingannuityspecialist.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/retirement.jpg" class="productImage"  width="<%=view.imageWidth%>" height="<%=view.imageHeight%>"  />
                        <div class="canvas-wrapper"  style="position:absolute; width:<%=view.width%>px; height:<%=view.height%>px; left: <%=view.left%>px; top: <%=view.top%>px;">
                                <canvas id="<%=view.applicationType%>_<%=view.viewId%>" width="<%=view.width%>" height="<%=view.height%>" ></canvas>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        <% }); %>

</script>


<body>

<div  id="target_container"  style="width:100%; height:100%;">



</div>
<button onClick="addImage()">Add Image </button>


<script>

/* List of canvas */ 
var canvas;
    var viewDetailsList=[
        {
        "width":1880,"height":977,"top":0,"left":0,"imageWidth":1880,"imageHeight":977,"viewId":2603,"title":"front","imageSrc":"1.png","applicationType":"editor"
        }]

        var template = $("#canvas-template").html();
        $('#target_container').html(_.template(template)({viewList:viewDetailsList}));

        var $targetContainer=$('#target_container');

        /* Calculate Scale Factor according to Outer container */
        function calculateScaleFactor(viewId) {
            var viewContainer = $('[data-editor-view-id="' + viewId + '"]');
            var cssWidthScale = $targetContainer.width() / viewContainer.width();
            var cssHeightScale = $targetContainer.height() / viewContainer.height();
            var scaleFactor = Math.min(cssWidthScale, cssHeightScale);
            return scaleFactor;
        }
        /* Fit Canvas to perticular target or div according to width and height of div 
         Let's say If I wan to fix perticular canvas of width 1000px and height 1000px to 500px by 500px then I waant to calculate the scaleFactor for fitting 1000px canvas inside the 500px area. 
        */
        function setCanvasCSS(viewId){
            var scaleFactor= calculateScaleFactor(viewId);
            var viewContainer = $('[data-editor-view-id="' + viewId + '"]');
            var scaling= 'scale(' + scaleFactor + ',' + scaleFactor + ')'
            viewContainer.css({'transform': scaling,'-webkit-transform': scaling,'-moz-transform': scaling,'-o-transform': scaling});
            var leftPos = ($targetContainer.width() - viewContainer.width() * scaleFactor) / 2;
            var topPos = ($targetContainer.height() - viewContainer.height() * scaleFactor) / 2;
            viewContainer.css({'left': leftPos,'top':topPos});

        }
        /* Iteration for Multiple Canvas*/
        $.each(viewDetailsList,function(key, view){
            setCanvasCSS(view.viewId);
        })

        /*Window.Resize canvas setting */
        $(window).resize(function(){
            setCanvasCSS(viewDetailsList[0].viewId);
                canvas.getObjects().forEach(function(obj){
                obj.setCoords();
                canvas.renderAll();
                 canvas.calcOffset();
            })

          });

         /* Create Canvas */
         canvas = new fabric.Canvas('editor_2603');

        /* Add Image */
         function addImage(){
            var imgURL = 'http://i.imgur.com/8rmMZI3.jpg';
             var imgObj = new Image();
            imgObj.src = imgURL
            imgObj.onload = function() {
              var image = new fabric.Image(imgObj);
              image.set({
                left: 10,
                top: 10,
              }).scale(0.2);
              canvas.add(image);
              image.setCoords();
              canvas.renderAll();
              canvas.calcOffset();

            };


         }
</script>  



<style>
 #target_container{border:1px solid red;}
 .view-wrapper{transform-origin:0% 0%;overflow:hidden;}
 .canvas-wrapper{border: 5px solid green;}

</style>

</body>
</html>
```